# ASP Images Refreshing until first cycle

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I am working on an ASP project (fairly new to ASP) one weird thing I have noticed is that images appear to refresh until after the first circle of images, my page code is:

```
            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:Image runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/1.png" ID="updateImage"></asp:Image>
                <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
            </ContentTemplate>
        <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Button1" EventName="click" />
        </Triggers>    
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

And the code behind is:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if (updateImage.ImageUrl != "~/Images/8.png")
            {
                //Get Image number
                string image = updateImage.ImageUrl.ToString();
                char[] file = image.ToCharArray();
                int fileName = Convert.ToInt32(file[9].ToString());
                fileName++;
                updateImage.ImageUrl = "~/Images/" + fileName.ToString() + ".png";
            }else
            {

                updateImage.ImageUrl = "~/Images/1.png";
            }
        }
```

When I click the button the first cycle of 8 images looks as though the page is reloading, but after that there is no reload on the page and the images just change smoothly, is this because ASP caches the images after the first cycle? Is there any way to stop it flickering on the first cycle?

Thanks.

Comment: @mason I'm not very adept on the MVC model, I would consider moving but would be interested to know why Web Forms cause this refresh in any event.

Comment: Have you checked in your browser to see what the network says about the image? Whether it's grabbing it from cache or fetching fresh every time? Look at the network tab of your browser's dev tools.

Comment: @mason Thanks for that, looking at the dev tools it looks like it does grab them from the server the first time, after that it doesn't. Similarly the Page_Load method is called for the first cycle of images but after that is never called?

Comment: Are you sure Page_Load is not called again? How are you verifying that?

Comment: @mason Apologies, it is but the images are not grabbed again so not causing a 'flicker'

Comment: @ajones756 So if the flicker is caused by having to load the images for the first time, why not have all the images on the page but just hidden? Then use JavaScript to selectively hide/show them? Or instead of using an UpdatePanel (which is one of the worst things you can use in Web Forms) just use some JavaScript to grab the image and swap it out. Then you could even use transitions like a fade out/in to be less jarring visibly.